# Are some of the new age proponents in psychosis?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, psychosis

[Psychosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychosis) refers to an abnormal condition of the mind described as involving a "loss of contact with reality". -Wikipedia

When I listen to person who practices [new age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Age), I often think that is the person in some kind of psychosis. They talk eg. about special powers got from the stone, telepathy or connection to some kind of divine powers, etc.

Comment: You question got closed since it is unclear. Perhaps read a bit more into the [Wikipedia article on Psychosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychosis) and refine your question with what you learned. You can still edit your question, after which it can be reopened.